# Clojure: Function to get upper triangular matrix given a matrix

Tags: clojure

I'm very new to Clojure, and I was trying to implement from scratch (I don't want to use any module) a function to get some sort of triangular matrix from an original matrix, like so:

```
((1 2 3) (4 5 6) (7 8 9)) --> ((1 2 3) (5 6) (9))
```

I could get this to work using recursion but I also wanted to achieve this without using recursion, if possible. Any idea would be much appreciated.

The way I solved this using recursion is:

```
(defn get-sup-triang [m]
  (cond
    (empty? (rest (first m))) m
    true (cons (first m) (get-sup-triang (rest (map rest m))))))
```

Comment: When you say "without recursion", what do you have in mind? do you want to use [loop](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop)/[recur](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/recur), which is similar to your approach, or something different?

Comment: Why do you represent that matrix as ((1 2 3) (5 6) (9)) and not ((1 2 3) (0 5 6) (0 0 9))?

Comment: It has to do with something besides the point, I could add zeros to the result with not much effort anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `drop` to get rid of the 0-n elements from the front.  If
you use it with a `map` you can feed both a simple range and your matrix.

E.g.

```
(map drop (range) matrix)
; ((1 2 3) (5 6) (9))
```

Comment: or just `(map-indexed drop matrix)` , without an intermediate collection for `range`

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm still far too unfamiliar with the primitive functions Clojure offers and I find it hard coming up with ways to use them together